# Exit stamp date not clear; problematic for future?

Tags: passport-stamps

So I got a visa on arrival in a non-Schengen European country for 21 days and everything went smoothly; I got then stamped entry with a clear date and so I enjoyed 7 great days in this country. After 7 days, I traveled back to my country and so everything is fine as I respected the visa rules given and did not overstay.

However, the exit stamp on the visa on my passport has the day and almost the month clearly visible but is missing the '1' in the year '17' and so the year doesn't appear clearly.

My questions:

1. Will this be ever perceived as a problem for future visas and entries (**EDIT: for other countries, not the same country since I am sure that electronically everything is fine for this country**)? I am worried that it may be perceived as 'overstayed' since the complete date is not clear even though I have the same date stamped back as entry to my home country.
2. Usually if people overstay, do they get an 'overstayed' stamp? In that case, any future officer will not care about the date of my exit since there is no 'overstayed' stamp?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: For #2, you will get much better answers if you say which country.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's **highly unlikely** that an unclear stamp will be a problem, since what matters is the electronic records stored by that country, not the ink in your passport, which may be replaced, lost, damaged etc anyway.

   It's equally unlikely that other countries will care, since it's not their business and immigration officers are unlikely to be familiar with the intricacies of what exactly counts as an overstay in some other country anyway (eg. Schengen's 90/180 rule has been known to baffle even Schengen immigration officials).
2. Yes, it's common to explicitly stamp overstays, deportations, etc.

Comment: Please see the edit and review accordingly...

Answer (score 4):

If you are concerned about other countries being upset about you having potentially overstayed, you can carry alternative proof that you really did exit the country at the time you say you did (e.g. an entrance stamp from another country, airline boarding pass, etc.). However, if only the tens digit of the year is missing I would be extremely surprised if anyone thought you had overstayed based on this -- at least not until 2027, when you will have gotten a new passport anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Most countries ignore other countries' stamps most of the time.  But more importantly, most passports are valid for no more than ten years.  The only year that both ends in seven and falls within your passport's period of validity is 2017.  If anyone ever calls that stamp into question, you can point this out.

Everyone knows that passport stamps are sometimes applied carelessly.  There's nothing to worry about here.